# Codeigniter Security Offset issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an update function which is very simple, I just have done the function, it doesn't communicate with any other controller or models, I receieve error below each time this function is called,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 543

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 543

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 3

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 543
```

I have all other type of functions on my application and this is the only one that throws this error

This is my view on edit:

```
<div class="warper container-fluid">

<div class="page-header"><h1>Edit case study</h1></div>

<?php   echo validation_errors(); ?>   
<?php if (isset($success_msg)) {echo $success_msg;} ?>
<?php if (isset($error_msg)) {echo $error_msg;} ?>


<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Please fill the form below</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/update_this_case" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-flat" placeholder="Title" name="case_study_title" value="<?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_title; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="dotted">


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Active</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="Please select one" name="case_study_active">
          <?php if($edit_case_study->case_study_active == '0') { ?> 

                 <option value="0" select="selected">No</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>

                <?php } else { ?>

                <option value="1" select="selected">Yes</option>
                <option value="0" >No</option>

               <?php } ?> 
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

     <hr class="dotted">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Content</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
     <textarea class="wysihtml form-control" placeholder="Enter main content ..." style="height: 200px" name="case_study_content"><?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_body; ?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Current Image</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="preview preview-md"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/<?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_header_img; ?>"/></div>
</div>
</div>

     <hr class="dotted">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
       <input type="file" name="case_study_img" id="fileToUpload">
      </div>
    </div>


    <hr class="dotted">

      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Link</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-flat" placeholder="Add a link" name="case_study_link" value="<?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_link; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>

     <hr class="dotted">

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Video</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-flat" placeholder="Add a link" name="case_study_video" value="<?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_video; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>

     <hr class="dotted">

     <input type="hidden" name="case_study_id" value="<?php echo $edit_case_study->case_study_id; ?>">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple pull-right" name="my_update_case">Submit</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function update_this_case(){
        if (isset($_POST['my_update_case'])) {echo "Yes";}
    } // end of function
```

there is nothing else about it, I can't put my head around it. I can't find any documentation or anything like it. Can you please help?

//// Edit ///

I just realised, it has issue with my text area, so I created a new content and added a simple content with not links inside and I didn't see this error. Does it have to do with my post?

Comment: What version are you using? Just so I can see what is on line #543.

Comment: V2.2.0 - I have found what triggers these errors, if XSS  global in my config is on then it throws this error, it seems it doesn't like links and embedded images in textarea. I turned it off and worked just fine, but this is not right, I need to be able to have it on for security purposes obviously so need to find out how to overcome this issue

Comment: You need to read the documentation on the form helper class.  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html  Look at the form_open, form_error and set_value guides to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is XSS global needs to be TURNED OFF in config.php

I hope this helps others with same issue.

Thanks all for your inputs.

Comment: Why turn it off, you can simply allow the characters that you want, in `config/config.php`